# Error while running junit for camel application connecting to hornetQ

Tags: spring, junit, apache-camel, jbossfuse, hornetq

I'm trying to write a JUnit test for a camel application which connects to hornet Q. The configurations is below. The application is working fine in container.

In the actual application I'm using an embedded hornetQ which comes with fuse 6.3. The connection factory is defined in standalone-full XML and I'm using `java:/ConnectionFactory` in the `JNDIObjectfactorybean`.

I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [META-INF/spring/bean-declarations.xml]: Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException:
>   scheme java not recognized

Standalone full xml messaging subsystem configuration:

```
        <jms-connection-factories>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                <connectors>
                    <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                </connectors>
                <entries>
                    <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                </entries>
            </connection-factory>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                <connectors>
                    <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                </connectors>
                <entries>
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                </entries>
            </connection-factory>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                <transaction mode="xa"/>
                <connectors>
                    <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                </connectors>
                <entries>
                    <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                </entries>
            </pooled-connection-factory>
        </jms-connection-factories>
```

Bean declarations for hornetQ JMS component:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/ConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hornetq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

In order to mock the HornetQ server I have added the below hornerQ configuration in test resources as below.

hornetq-configuration.xml:

```
 <configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq">

    <paging-directory>target/data/paging</paging-directory>
    <bindings-directory>target/data/bindings</bindings-directory>
    <persistence-enabled>false</persistence-enabled>
    <journal-directory>target/data/journal</journal-directory>
    <journal-min-files>10</journal-min-files>
    <large-messages-directory>target/data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
    <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>

    <connectors>
        <connector name="invm-connector">
            <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory</factory-class>
        </connector>
    </connectors>

    <acceptors>
        <acceptor name="invm-acceptor">
            <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
        </acceptor>
    </acceptors>

</configuration>
```

hornetq-jms.xml :

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq">

    <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory">
        <connectors>
            <connector-ref connector-name="invm-connector" />
        </connectors>

        <entries>
            <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory" />
        </entries>
    </connection-factory>

    <queue name="TEST.QUEUE">
        <entry name="TEST.QUEUE" />
    </queue>

</configuration>
```

Error details while running JUnit:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [META-INF/spring/bean-declarations.xml]: Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException:
>   scheme java not recognized    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:618)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader.loadContext(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader.loadContext(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:95)
>     ... 25 more Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: scheme java not
>   recognized    at
>   org.apache.camel.util.jndi.JndiContext.lookup(JndiContext.java:218)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)  at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
>     ... 38 more

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see where Spring is configured to actually start the mock HornetQ server.  I also don't see where you've configured the JNDI lookup to use the proper initial context factory for the HornetQ resources.  The exception is coming from org.apache.camel.util.jndi.JndiContext which indicates Spring is attempting to use Camel code to do a JNDI lookup for HornetQ resources.

Comment: Hi justin,Can you share some reference example on how to mock and start hornetQ server.?

Comment: HornetQ ships with an example of this.  Check the distribution at <HORNETQ_HOME>/examples/jms/spring-integration.